# How to get Wordpress categories (the_categories()) via DB (SQL)

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, plugins

## What I need and why

Because of my plugins (WC_Membership) `get_categories()` is filtered due to restricted content.

Now I need every category listed for comparison reasons (which I would do via `get_categories()`), but not all categories are listed if not admin. Is SQL the way to go for my problem? **(Dont use WP_Query -> would get filtered by the other plugin)**

TL;DR: I need unfiltered categories - probably via SQL

## Normaly I do ...

```
$cats = [];
foreach (get_categories() as $key => $value) {            
   $cats[] = $value->cat_ID;
}
echo "Cats: ".implode(',',$cats);
```

Will return `Cats: 1,225,228,494,490,492,232,241,233,234,235,236,237,238,242` (unfiltered as admin).

When a user with restrictions runs this script, they would get something like `Cats: 1,225,228` (but I need all categories listed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correct understand you:

```
SELECT wp_terms.term_id
FROM wp_term_relationships
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
   ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_terms on wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_terms.term_id
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
GROUP BY wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
```

This SQL get all taxonomies from database. Hope help you

Comment: Works smoothly, but it returns the nice_names instead of the ID. I tried to swap `SELECT wp_terms.name` with `SELECT wp_terms.ID`, but it's still not returning the ID. Could you please edit your answer to provide the ID. Thank you allready!